# Magento 2 : Error 500 - Internal server error while creating the large varient configurable products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am not able to create a large variant of configurable products. It's showing me the error like `Error 500 - Internal server error` after processing some minute of time. After processing the configurable product it's only generating some of the products not all. There is no error in a log file.

So is there any way that can be useful for creating a large number of variant products at the time of creating this configurable product?

Comment: how many child products / variations does the parent configurable have? Is the 501 happening in the backend or when viewing the product in the frontend?

Comment: right now i need to create approx 85 products but it's only created a maximum 58 to 60 products. The issue is occurring while saving the configurable products in admin. The page is reloading for few second and then its redirect on 500 & created only 60 product of that variant.

Comment: Ok, 50 - 100 is not a lot. You need to try and track down the error that’s causing the 500 error. Check all your server logs. You can also, check your php timeout settings.